# In MVC set focus on first list item in ListView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, listview

I have an MVC project with many list views.  I want the focus to be set on the first item in the list view, so that a user can just hit enter to open that item? or use the arrow buttons to move up or down the list then hit enter.

I already do something similar for data entry views where I focus on the first textbox or combobox.  This is the code I use for that:

```
$('.focus :input').focus();
```

Then in my view:

```
<div class="col-md-3 focus">
     @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, "Select Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

That works perfectly, so now I want to do it with my list views.  This is what I tried:

```
$('.focus tr:first').focus();
```

and in my view:

```
<tr class="focus">
```

and unfortunately that does not work. So, I did a search and I cannot find any answers for MVC, I can find answers for android, metro apps, etc. but nothing for MVC.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/focus/

`focus()` is designed to work on a subset of elements, such as form inputs and anchors.

It doesn't work for standard markup elements such as table rows or divs etc.

What you could possibly do is to use an anchor within a list item element

`<li><a href="#">List Item<a></li>` and then set focus on the anchor ... `$('li a').focus();`

Comment: I don't want it to just look like it has focus.  I want it to have focus so a user can enter the record by hitting enter.

Comment: html elements such as table rows don't have the concept of having focus. i.e. you cannot tab to a table row. You can only focus form inputs, selects, anchors & buttons. What you could possibly to is use an anchor within a list item element `<li><a href="#">List Item<a></li>` and then set focus on the anchor ... `$('li a').focus();`

Comment: Thank you David - that is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do to set the first element.  I have tried modifying it for your `html`.

```
$('[selector for your dropdown]').focus();
$('[selector for your dropdown]').val($('[selector for your dropdown] option:first').val()).change();
```

Comment: fran, I am not trying to do anything with my dropdown. I just used that as an example.  I am talking about a table I have and I want to select the first record in the table. Thank you for your assistance though.